# Referencing/relating content between content types

Tags: nodes

I'm completely noob on Drupal, actualy I'm trying to find a way to build a website idea using it.

I want to let users/visitors to create travel tips, so at this site I'll have contents like: Countries, States, Cities, Places and tips.

A tip must be related with a Place, that is related to a City and a State Country. Also a tip must contain any number of images related to it.

The thing is, I' just can't find a way to do it with a fresh install on Drupal, neither find somewhere I can see an code example of it, if I need to really code it.

I thought in creating a Entity type, but didn't found how to do it without coding, and I also need a way to let users upload any number of images they want, and them show everything on a page (I believe this is the easiest part, after I get the other ones).

Anyone can help me with a quick way to figure this out? Maybe a few blog post links, a ebook, videocast, anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll find a quick solution. Creating content types and relating them via entity reference is a good start, but you'll need to spend time getting familiar with Drupal basics first. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @cdmo, after reading a few things, I'm wondering where can I get a full drupal tutorial on doing something as I mentioned. Every document is too superficial or too deep. I'm completely lost hehehe

Comment: You'll probably have difficulty finding a tutorial that shows you *exactly* how to do this, but poking around the Entity Reference module's documentation would help.  You may already be familiar, but getting the basics of content types might help: https://www.drupal.org/node/21947 .  If you're willing to pay, lynda.com and drupalize.me have some good overview tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Entity Reference Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference):

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
>
> - A generic entity reference field
> - Four widgets:
>
>   - Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes),
>   - Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with
>       comma-separated entries in the same text field)
> - Two formatters:
>
>   - A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the
>       referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
>   - A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a
>       configurable view mode
> - Integration with Views (for both forward and
>     backward references)
> - Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a
>     consequence with Search API and the like)
> - Integration with Devel generate
> - Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data import

That should get you started.